# Div content Page titles in Veritcal Scroll Site

Tags: php, html, css

Whats the easiest way to enable my page title to update per content div areas it's on?

I have a vertical scrolling website and would like the page title to change when the user navs to each content area (The content areas are within div & article)

Essentially, I'm trying to keep 'Orginal Site Title | + Home/About etc'

I'm thinking it's something I'd have to call with php to remember a set title attribute per div link? Any suggestions on setting this up (If possible)

Comment: By "nav," do you mean scrolling? Like, change the `<title>` based on whichever content box takes up the most (vertical) space on the screen?

Comment: Yea, Ideally that'd be great. But I was figuring I'd have to settle for when the user would navigate by button links. Click About, You get the nice scroll all the way down some 3000 for the about area - then as that content would come up the title would update " Original | + Welcome to about "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should take a look at the [Viewport plugin](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/viewport). This way you have 4 selectors you can use:

```
$(":in-viewport")
$(":below-the-fold")
$(":above-the-top")
$(":left-of-screen")
$(":right-of-screen")
```

Now you could do something like this:

```
//Get the id of element(div) that is currently in view
var inview = $('div:in-viewport:first').attr('id');

//Define titles
if (inview == 'home'){

var newtitle = 'Home'

} else if (inview == 'about') {

var newtitle = 'About us'

} 

//Lets rename the page title
document.title = 'Orginal Site Title |' + newtitle;
```

The above code should now always be called when you scroll (`$(window).scroll(function () { ... });`) to update page title according to the div that is currently in view.

This is just a generic example and it can be completely changed to your needs. I hope it helps in some way.

Comment: This looks good; while I don't have support on the project I was working on before to test this feature - this is definitely something I'm going to try and give a test next time.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do this by writing a plugin based on the scrollspy plugin that comes as part of twitter bootstrap: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#scrollspy

You could tweak it so rather than setting a class on the target it updates the title with whatever the content is in the current viewable panel